# AWS dynamoDB limit or pagination, when fetching from unsorted table (ios)

Tags: ios, pagination, limit, amazon-dynamodb

I have an unsorted table (only hash key, without range key).

I must search and fetch limit rows from table. If I use the `limit` property of `AWSDynamoDBScanExpression`. But this limit property is not working: I get responses with less than `count` elements when using the `limit` property.

I read about pagination - `exclusiveStartKey` and `LastEvaluatedKey` properties, but it is good for sorted data. I have unsorted data. And my data must be unsorted and return random rows with limit in every query.

Roughly speaking, I need to start and limit analogs from SQL, but for dynamoDB. It is possible? I do not understand how to do this with a `scan` operation. Please help me set a limit of fetched rows.

Comment: Are you trying to get random sampling from Dynamo, or are you trying to scan through your whole table and only get certain rows on a condition, or are ? I am kind of confused by your requirements and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have table with 6000+ rows.
I trying
1) filter table (300+ rows fall under the condition)
2) from filtred rows fetch few random rows (5 for example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exclusiveStartKey` is the equivalent of `offset`.

The DynamoDB API `limit` is **an API limit** - not an application limit.

It doesn't make sure you get `<= limit` elements. It just forces a single request to return `<= limit`  elements and set the next chunk via `LastEvaluatedKey`

To randomize the response, you will have to fetch more events than you might need and randomly select between them.

Comment: Can some one please share a link of AWS Docs - where pagination is explained using Dynamodb + API Gateway (proxy service) combination

Comment: @macmold This document has some explanation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.Pagination

Comment: @AbdealiChandanwala I'm also struggling with this hardly, did you find the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920146/api-gatway-proxy-response-when-using-exclusivestartkey