# API Gatway proxy response when using ExclusiveStartKey

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

Consider [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.html#GettingStarted.NodeJs.04.Scan) from docs for Amazon DynamoDB, here we have:

```
dynamoDb.scan(params, onScan);

function onScan(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          return;
      } else {
        collectedItems.push(data.Items);

        const response = {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(collectedItems),
        };
        callback(null, response);

        // continue scanning if we have more movies, because
        // scan can retrieve a maximum of 1MB of data
        if (typeof data.LastEvaluatedKey != "undefined") {
            console.log("Scanning for more...");
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
            dynamoDb.scan(params, onScan);
        }



      }
  }
```

that should show me `collectedItems` as json response for API Gateway. But it returns

```
{
 message: "Internal server error"
}
```

Comment: There appear to be multiple potential problems with your code, but for a start, don't swallow exceptions: `if (err) { return callback(err); }` ...then, review the Lambda logs and let's see what you find.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did that and that doesn't work still..Even I see `collectedItems` in logs and even the code in if block works as well. But, I'm not able to see the response when querying url for API Gateway..

Comment: What do you find in the API Gateway (not Lambda) logs?  502 suggests that API Gateway finds your Lambda function's response format to be syntactically/structurally invalid.  (Or an exception is thrown in Lambda, but presumably it isn't that).

Comment: Task timed out after 6.00 seconds. This is what I get in API Gateway logs.